# Set default column value with powershell pnp

Tags: pnp-powershell

I am trying to set a default value for a managed metadata field in a newly created library, can I achieve that with Set-PnPField?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Set-PnPDefaultColumnValues` command to set the value.

Use it as below:

```
Set-PnPDefaultColumnValues -List Documents -Field TaxKeyword 
-Value \"Company|Locations|Stockholm\""
```

where the term Stockholm is located in the Locations termset inside Company term group.

If you know the guid of the term, then you can do it as:

```
Set-PnPDefaultColumnValues -List Documents -Field TaxKeyword 
-Value \"15c4c4e4-4b67-4894-a1d8-de5ff811c791\""
```

Here, `TaxKeyword` is the internal name of the column inside `Documents` library.

Reference - [Set-PnPDefaultColumnValues](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpdefaultcolumnvalues?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: Hey @user3202981 , did you try this code ? If it worked for you, could you please mark it as answer ? Its just a tick besides the answer.